Compilation of MariaDB on Windows: Multiple cryptic errors
I'm trying to compile MariaDB from source on Windows 64-bit following the official documentation. During the compilation, many errors like the following (first one) occur:
[...]
pcre2_error.c
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(592,7): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: "Typ" [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld
\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(592,7): error C2059: int vfscanf (FILE *__stream,  const char *__format, __builtin_va
_list __local_argv) [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C
:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(592,7): error C2059: ^ (Quelldatei wird kompiliert C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\s
erver\bld\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2\src\pcre2_convert.c) [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2
-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(592,7): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: "Typ" [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld
\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(592,7): error C2059: int vfscanf (FILE *__stream,  const char *__format, __builtin_va
_list __local_argv) [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C
:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(592,7): error C2059: ^ (Quelldatei wird kompiliert C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\s
erver\bld\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2-build\pcre2_chartables.c) [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\extra\pcre2\src\
pcre2-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(599,7): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: "Typ" [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld
\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(599,7): error C2059: int vsscanf (const char * __restrict__ __source, const char * __
restrict__ __format, __builtin_va_list __local_argv) [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2
-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(599,7): error C2059: ^ (Quelldatei wird kompiliert C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\s
erver\bld\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2-build\pcre2_chartables.c) [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\extra\pcre2\src\
pcre2-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(599,7): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: "Typ" [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld
\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(599,7): error C2059: int vsscanf (const char * __restrict__ __source, const char * __
restrict__ __format, __builtin_va_list __local_argv) [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2
-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]

The part of the log output until the first error is shown below:
-- Configuring done (5.1s)
-- Generating done (16.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/stehl/Documents/MariaDB/server/bld
PS C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld> cmake --build . --config Debug
Microsoft (R)-Build-Engine, Version 16.11.2+f32259642 für .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

  1>Checking Build System
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/stehl/Documents/MariaDB/server/strings/CMakeLists.txt
  uca-dump.vcxproj -> C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\strings\Debug\uca-dump.exe
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/stehl/Documents/MariaDB/server/strings/CMakeLists.txt
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/stehl/Documents/MariaDB/server/zlib/CMakeLists.txt
  zlib.vcxproj -> C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\zlib\Debug\zlib.lib
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/stehl/Documents/MariaDB/server/mysys/CMakeLists.txt
  mysys.vcxproj -> C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\mysys\Debug\mysys.lib
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/stehl/Documents/MariaDB/server/strings/CMakeLists.txt
  strings.vcxproj -> C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\strings\Debug\strings.lib
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/stehl/Documents/MariaDB/server/dbug/CMakeLists.txt
  dbug.vcxproj -> C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\dbug\Debug\dbug.lib
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/stehl/Documents/MariaDB/server/extra/CMakeLists.txt
  comp_err.vcxproj -> C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\extra\Debug\comp_err.exe
  Generating ../include/mysqld_error.h.tmp
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/stehl/Documents/MariaDB/server/extra/CMakeLists.txt
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/stehl/Documents/MariaDB/server/scripts/CMakeLists.txt
  comp_sql.vcxproj -> C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\scripts\Debug\comp_sql.exe
  Generating mariadb_fix_privilege_tables_sql.c
  mariadb_system_tables_fix.sql
  mariadb_system_tables.sql
  mariadb_performance_tables.sql
  mariadb_sys_schema.sql
          1 Datei(en) kopiert.
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/stehl/Documents/MariaDB/server/scripts/CMakeLists.txt
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/stehl/Documents/MariaDB/server/CMakeLists.txt
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/stehl/Documents/MariaDB/server/CMakeLists.txt
  Building Java objects for JdbcInterface.jar
  -- Clean class files from previous build
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/stehl/Documents/MariaDB/server/storage/connect/CMakeLists.txt
  Generating CMakeFiles/JdbcInterface.dir/java_class_filelist
  Creating Java archive JdbcInterface.jar
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/stehl/Documents/MariaDB/server/libservices/CMakeLists.txt
  mysqlservices.vcxproj -> C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\libservices\Debug\mysqlservices.lib
  Creating directories for 'pcre2'
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/stehl/Documents/MariaDB/server/CMakeLists.txt
  Performing download step (download, verify and extract) for 'pcre2'
  -- verifying file...
         file='C:/Users/stehl/Documents/MariaDB/server/bld/extra/pcre2/src/pcre2-10.42.zip'
  -- File already exists and hash match (skip download):
    file='C:/Users/stehl/Documents/MariaDB/server/bld/extra/pcre2/src/pcre2-10.42.zip'
    MD5='fe90992fbfb03f854bd9f344074f49eb'
  -- extracting...
       src='C:/Users/stehl/Documents/MariaDB/server/bld/extra/pcre2/src/pcre2-10.42.zip'
       dst='C:/Users/stehl/Documents/MariaDB/server/bld/extra/pcre2/src/pcre2'
  -- extracting... [tar xfz]
  -- extracting... [analysis]
  -- extracting... [rename]
  -- extracting... [clean up]
  -- extracting... done
  No update step for 'pcre2'
  No patch step for 'pcre2'
  Performing configure step for 'pcre2'
  -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
  -- Found Readline: C:/msys64/mingw64/include
  -- Could not find OPTIONAL package Editline
  --
  --
  -- PCRE2-10.42 configuration summary:
  --
  --   Install prefix .................. : C:/Program Files (x86)/PCRE2
  --   C compiler ...................... : C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/
  14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
  --   C compiler flags ................ : /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /Zi /MP /we4700 /we4311 /we4477 /we4302 /we4090 /diag
  nostics:caret /MT /Zi /O2  /DNDEBUG /Gw -DDBUG_OFF
  --
  --   Build 8 bit PCRE2 library ....... : ON
  --   Build 16 bit PCRE2 library ...... : OFF
  --   Build 32 bit PCRE2 library ...... : OFF
  --   Enable JIT compiling support .... : OFF
  --   Use SELinux allocator in JIT .... : IGNORE
  --   Enable Unicode support .......... : ON
  --   Newline char/sequence ........... : LF
  --   \R matches only ANYCRLF ......... : OFF
  --   \C is disabled .................. : OFF
  --   EBCDIC coding ................... : OFF
  --   EBCDIC coding with NL=0x25 ...... : OFF
  --   Rebuild char tables ............. : OFF
  --   Internal link size .............. : 2
  --   Parentheses nest limit .......... : 250
  --   Heap limit ...................... : 20000000
  --   Match limit ..................... : 10000000
  --   Match depth limit ............... : MATCH_LIMIT
  --   Build shared libs ............... : OFF
  --   Build static libs ............... : ON
  --      with PIC enabled ............. : OFF
  --   Build pcre2grep ................. : OFF
  --   Enable JIT in pcre2grep ......... : ON
  --   Enable callouts in pcre2grep .... : ON
  --   Enable callout fork in pcre2grep. : ON
  --   Buffer size for pcre2grep ....... : 20480
  --   Build tests (implies pcre2test .. : OFF
  --                and pcre2grep)
  --   Link pcre2grep with libz ........ : ON
  --   Link pcre2grep with libbz2 ...... : ON
  --   Link pcre2test with libeditline . : Library not found
  --   Link pcre2test with libreadline . : ON
  --   Support Valgrind .................: OFF
  --   Use %zu and %td ..................: AUTO
  --   Install MSVC .pdb files ..........: OFF
  --
  -- Configuring done (0.5s)
  -- Generating done (0.2s)
  -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/stehl/Documents/MariaDB/server/bld/extra/pcre2/src/pcre2-build
  Performing build step for 'pcre2'
  Microsoft (R)-Build-Engine, Version 16.11.2+f32259642 für .NET Framework
  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

    1>Checking Build System
    Building Custom Rule C:/Users/stehl/Documents/MariaDB/server/bld/extra/pcre2/src/pcre2/CMakeLists.txt
    pcre2_auto_possess.c
    pcre2_chartables.c
    pcre2_compile.c
    pcre2_config.c
    pcre2_context.c
    pcre2_convert.c
    pcre2_dfa_match.c
    pcre2_error.c
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(592,7): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: "Typ" [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld
\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(592,7): error C2059: int vfscanf (FILE *__stream,  const char *__format, __builtin_va
_list __local_argv) [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C
:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(592,7): error C2059: ^ (Quelldatei wird kompiliert C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\s
erver\bld\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2\src\pcre2_convert.c) [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2
-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(592,7): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: "Typ" [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld
\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(592,7): error C2059: int vfscanf (FILE *__stream,  const char *__format, __builtin_va
_list __local_argv) [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C
:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(592,7): error C2059: ^ (Quelldatei wird kompiliert C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\s
erver\bld\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2-build\pcre2_chartables.c) [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\extra\pcre2\src\
pcre2-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(599,7): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: "Typ" [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld
\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(599,7): error C2059: int vsscanf (const char * __restrict__ __source, const char * __
restrict__ __format, __builtin_va_list __local_argv) [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2
-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(599,7): error C2059: ^ (Quelldatei wird kompiliert C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\s
erver\bld\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2-build\pcre2_chartables.c) [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\extra\pcre2\src\
pcre2-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(599,7): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: "Typ" [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld
\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(599,7): error C2059: int vsscanf (const char * __restrict__ __source, const char * __
restrict__ __format, __builtin_va_list __local_argv) [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2
-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(599,7): error C2059: ^ (Quelldatei wird kompiliert C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\s
erver\bld\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2\src\pcre2_convert.c) [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2
-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(605,7): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: "Typ" [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld
\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(605,7): error C2059: int vscanf(const char *__format,  __builtin_va_list __local_argv
) [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C:\Users\stehl\Docu
ments\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(605,7): error C2059: ^ (Quelldatei wird kompiliert C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\s
erver\bld\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2-build\pcre2_chartables.c) [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\extra\pcre2\src\
pcre2-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(605,7): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: "Typ" [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld
\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(605,7): error C2059: int vscanf(const char *__format,  __builtin_va_list __local_argv
) [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C:\Users\stehl\Docu
ments\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(605,7): error C2059: ^ (Quelldatei wird kompiliert C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\s
erver\bld\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2\src\pcre2_convert.c) [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2
-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(592,7): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: "Typ" [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld
\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(592,7): error C2059: int vfscanf (FILE *__stream,  const char *__format, __builtin_va
_list __local_argv) [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C
:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(592,7): error C2059: ^ (Quelldatei wird kompiliert C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\s
erver\bld\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2\src\pcre2_context.c) [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2
-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(592,7): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: "Typ" [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld
\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdio.h(592,7): error C2059: int vfscanf (FILE *__stream,  const char *__format, __builtin_va
_list __local_argv) [C:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\extra\pcre2\src\pcre2-build\pcre2-8-static.vcxproj] [C
:\Users\stehl\Documents\MariaDB\server\bld\pcre2.vcxproj]

What did happen / Why do these errors occur? It looks to me like they are not caused by many single syntax errors (especially since the program is developed professionally), but by a common global cause unknown to me. The compiler version installed on my PC is Visual Studio 2019.
Since I am currently only interested in the syntax error diagnosis procedures, I would be happy with a minimal build without additional optional modules.

Thanks. In theory, the build process started by me should use Visual Studio ... I will try (how?) to find out why the stdio.h file was the one found in mingw (also installed on my PC), not that one provided by Visual Studio. In addition, I will use Visual Studio 2022 instead of 2019, despite the latter is supported too according to MariaDB's documentation.

I was not able to find out which paths are searched when INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES (a CMake variable) is empty, but it seemed to be the case that the PATH variable was looked up first before looking up the include directories given in the Visual Studio project. I had Mingw in my PATH variable, so its include directories where used instead of the Visual Studio ones (without checking if they fit to the compiler specified in cmake).
You are invited to formulate your comment as answer, such that I can accept it as the correct one. Thanks for your crucial observation!
